# Symfony My debug toolbar doesn't appear on my website anymore

Tags: symfony, debugging, toolbar

While debugging, I actually lost my debug toolbar (like, it doesn't appear anymore on my website) so I tried various thing to have it back:

```
composer require symfony/profiler-pack
composer require symfony/apache-pack
```

And even:

```
composer remove apache-pack
composer require symfony/apache-pack
```

But I still can't have it back. I found nothing that can help on the Internet.
Thanks !

Edit:
The command `bin/console debug:router _wdt` return this:

```
| Route Name   | _wdt    |
| Path         | /_wdt/{token}                                                |
| Path Regex   | #^/_wdt/(?P<token>[^/]++)$#sD                                |
| Host         | ANY                                                          |
| Host Regex   |                                                              |
| Scheme       | ANY                                                          |
| Method       | ANY                                                          |
| Requirements | NO CUSTOM                                                    |
| Class        | Symfony\Component\Routing\Route                              |
| Defaults     | _controller: web_profiler.controller.profiler::toolbarAction |
| Options      | compiler_class: Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCompiler
```

Comment: Are you in dev env in your .env.local ?

Comment: Yes I am in dev.

Comment: I assume you are generating more or less valid html pages still?  The bar only shows up when the html is reasonably valid.  If something else is going on then you might not see it.  Otherwise, does "bin/console debug:router" show the debug routes?  What happens if you try some of those routes manually?

Comment: Yes. `debug:router` shows a lot of routes. For example, the login is one of them and if I go on the login route, I don't have my profiler bar.

Comment: I'm talking about the _wdt route which is used by the profiler.  "bin/console debug:router _wdt" It will tell you if the profiler code is installed and enabled.

Comment: I edited my question with the return of this command.

Answer (score 2):

In `.env.local` AND `.env.dev` be sure `APP_ENV=dev` and `APP_DEBUG=1`

Also, in `config/packages/dev/web_profiler.yaml` you have something like

```
web_profiler:
    toolbar: true
```

Also, if you change any values in these you should clear your cache `php bin/console cache:clear`

Your Response also needs to contain the `<body>` tag or the toolbar won't show

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already have `toolbar: true` in web_profiler.yaml. Also, I don't have the .env.dev but I put the two env var in my .env.local, still not working